# Новый класс C# в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, классы

Вероятно, вопрос будет выглядеть глупо для вас, но я так и не смог найти ответ в православном гугле. Короче, у меня есть программка WPF, я для удобства создал отдельный класс C#, обрабатывающий логику, почти не связанную с XAML. Вот только мне все равно нужно периодически обращаться к некоторым элементам (кнопкам например). Но видны они только в классе `public partial class MainWindow : Window`. Как мне использовать элементы программы в новом C# классе?

Comment: есть для таких целей паттерны https://metanit.com/sharp/patterns/

Comment: Сергей, хоть вам и заминусовали вопрос, не отчаивайтесь, вы мыслите в правильном направлении. Именно желание отвязаться от UI(XAML) кода и породило такие паттерны как MVC, MVP и MVVM. Узнайте о них больше, чтобы улучшить свои навыки проектирования приложений)

Answer (score 1):

Такие проблемы принято решать с помощью паттерна [MVVM](https://habr.com/ru/post/338518/) и [других](https://habr.com/ru/post/215605/) паттернов